# Linking bridged calls from queue

Tags: php, asterisk, voip, asteriskami

I made a PHP script that calls 10 numbers and if they answer they are put in a queue and if there are free agents they pick up each call.

My problem is I cannot log which number is bridged to which extension.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is check queue_log.

It can be writted to mysql  table.

When call come to queue you see it callerid,uniqueid, queue name. After it answered by someone you can see uniqueid and agent's name or device.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+queue_log+on+MySQL